# Eclipse Classic Version Differences?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working on an Android project now where everyone (about 12 people) are using the Eclipse Galileo IDE 3.5.2.  That decision was made last year when that version was relatively current.  But we're at a good milestone where, if we wanted to make any changes, this would be a good time to do it, although we're not having any problems with Galileo.   We're using the latest SDK.

Where can I get an idea of what the differences and improvements are between the different versions of Eclipse Classic's, (e.g. Galileo vs Helios) so I can form an opinion about whether we should switch to the latest version?   (the latest version of Classic is 3.6)

Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse Project download page for each major release has a link to a [New and Noteworthy](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news.html) page which has an overview of the new stuff.